# Is using Kafka as an input source for Flink a performance bottleneck?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

Flink allows to read from a Kafka topic, is that a performance bottleneck making Flink slower overall?

Comment: It depends on your use case. What is the alternative to Kafka? You need to have an input of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka partitions can scale horizontally to accomodate for higher thoughput.

One Flink consumer thread can only be assigned to one Kafka partition.

So, if you have only 1 Kafka partition, and `N+1` Flink executors, then you will have `N` idle tasks, which could be a bottleneck, sure, but that is a tradeoff of having total-ordering within a Kafka topic, not necessarily a Flink problem.

Otherwise, you would create your Kafka topics with ten to hundreds of partitions, and Flink would be fine to consume it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If, for example, you have a slow network connection between your Kafka cluster and your Flink cluster, then that will become a performance bottleneck.